# Status 7: Can't GET movie by ID using TMDB API

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, axios

I'm trying to use the [TMDB API](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3) to create a simple app. I'm using Axios to make the HTTP requests.

I started by retrieving the 20 latest movies, so far so good, manage to display that no problems.

The issue begin when I tried to get the details for a single movie. Searched some solutions but it seems to always present the same error: "Status 7: Invalid API key (or Status 401)".

This is my Axios config:

```
const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/';

const HEADERS = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  Accept: 'application/json',
};

const PARAMS = {
  params: {
    api_key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  }
};

const client = axios.create({
      BASE_URL,
      HEADERS,    
      PARAMS,
    });
```

In a previous iteration I've tried including the API key has a 'Authorization' header, but it had the same problem.

By the status code, you may be quick to think something is wrong with my API key, but that doesn't seems to be an issue getting the latest movies, plus the I've triple checked it by now.

EDIT: I'm using ReactJS and Redux, I'm sure the problem doesn't come from there, seen I've use basically the same configuration with a local server, before starting this project, and without an API key there was no issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. The problem was a CORS issue, I was trying to make request without the CORS headers. Plus my Axios config was wrong.

The way I solve it was by using CORS Anywhere, with my API BASE URL:

```
const BASE_URL = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.themoviedb.org/3";
```

I saw other ways of adding the CORS headers, including a chrome extension called CORS, but that would cause other issues. So I guess this is the simplest solution.